# $ a \lvert b$ and $b \lvert c$ implies $a \lvert \left(bx + cy \right)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

basically I just want to check if my proof's correct for the theorem written in the title.

Theorem: $ a \lvert b$ and $b \lvert c$ implies $a \lvert \left(bx + cy \right)$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Proof:

Assume that $a \lvert b$ and $b \lvert c$. Therefore there exists $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b = am$ and $c = bn$. Since $a \lvert b$ and $b \lvert c$ implies $a \lvert c$ there also exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $c = ak$. From this, $bx + cy = amx + aky$. Dividing this by $a$ gives a number $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d = mx + ky$ and $ad = amx + aky = bx + cy$. Therefore if $a \lvert b$ and $b \lvert c$ then $a \lvert \left(bx + cy \right)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. $\blacksquare$

Questions:

- Is the logic here correct?
- Can I just assume that $bx + cy = amx + aky$?
- Do I have to explicitly say that $a, b, \ldots \ne 0$?
- Do I also have to assume that $a, b, \ldots \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Your logic is correct. Also you got $bx+cy=amx+aky$ by systematic deductions so it is not an assumption. $a,b$ are non-zero from the hypothesis itself ($a|b$ hence $a$ has to be non-zero. SImilarly for $b$). Also $a,b \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: The logic is correct, but it could have been more direct.  Letting $b=am$ and $c=bn$ you have $bx+cy = amx+amny = a(mx+mny)$.  You don't need to specify that the numbers are nonzero because the definitions for divisibility work for zero as well.  Every number divides zero.  As for assuming $a,b,\dots\in \Bbb Z$, at the very least $a,b,c$ need to be elements of some euclidean domain where the concept of divisibility makes sense and such that you can multiply them by integers and still make sense, but yes at the level of the question it makes sense to assume they are all integers.

Comment: @VikrantDesai $a\mid b$ if and only if there exists an integer $n$ such that $b=na$.  With this definition, we can say that $5\mid 0$ since we can pick $n=0$ to satisfy $0=n\cdot 5$.  Similarly, we can say $0\mid 0$ since $0=0\cdot 0$.  The definition does not make a special case for zero because it doesn't need to.  The hypotheses given in this question to not prevent any of the variables $a,b,c,x,y$ from being zero, however the only thing $0$ divides is $0$ so if $a$ is zero, so too are $b$ and $c$

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, but I did not get your point. We know that divisibility by zero is absurd. Also I did not understand why you say $0$ divides $0$. Apologies from my side if I couldn't understand you. Also the definition of divisibility for integers itself is "An integer $b$ is said to be divisible by a **non-zero** integer $a$ if there is an integer $k$ such that $b=ak$". So we don't have restrictions on $k$ and $b$ but $a$ must be non-zero. Thanks.

Comment: @Vikrant We know that we cannot **divide by zero**, but *divisibility* in reference to zero is not the same thing.  The bolded phrase "non-zero" in your cited definition is left out usually and only included if they want to state the equivalence between the phrases $a\mid b, \frac{b}{a}\in\Bbb Z, b\equiv 0\pmod{a}$ etc... where zeroes can cause things to be undefined.  There are plenty of cases where people allow $a$ and/or $b$ to be zero, e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134341/zero-is-divisible-by-every-integer-but-other-integers-are-not-divisible-by-zero).

Comment: @VikrantDesai see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Extrema) where in its description of posets they give the example of the non-negative integers partially ordered by divisibility with $0$ as the maximum element and $1$ as the minimum element of the poset.

Comment: @VikrantDesai - Incidentally (and somewhat irrelevantly) for $z\neq 0$  *Apostol* defines $z/0$ to be $\infty$ in the extended complex number system.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh that's great. I was taught and have encountered only the definition which I mentioned in my earlier comment. Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the logic here correct?
>
> Can I just assume that $bx + cy = amx + aky$?

Your proof seems correct, but there's some room for improvement. Your assumption of $bx + cx = amx + aky$ follows from the definition of divisibility.

The improvement you could do is after using the definition and come to the conclusion that theres $n$ and $m$ such that $b=am$ and $c=bn$ you can move directly from that. Then $bx+cy= amx + bny = amx +amny$.

Also you don't need mentioning division. You can just move from there and state that $bx+cy=(mx+mny)a$.

> Do I have to explicitly say that $a, b, \ldots \ne 0$?

No, you just use the definition of divisibility. There's no concern with any actual division by zero. For example we can allow zero "denominator" here if the "nominator" is zero: we have $0|0$ since there's an $k$ such that $0=k\cdot 0$ (the definition does not require $k$ to be unique, just that there's at least one).

> Do I also have to assume that $a, b, \ldots \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Yes, normally one assumes that it's integers without saying. It could also be that the requirement of it is in the definition of $a|b$. You also use that $x$ and $y$ are integers (in order to make $mn+mny$ integer).